# $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ bundles and genus 2 curve fibrations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I've been constructing genus 2 curve fibrations by starting with a (3,2) curve in $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P^1}$ and then promoting its scalar coefficients to sections of line bundles over some compact complex non-singular base variety $B$. So can I construct a $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P^1}$-bundle by just taking the product of two $\mathbb{P}^1$ bundles? Another way to to this would be to take a smooth quadric bundle, but my equations are easily written as a bi-homogeneous polynomial so I'd like to do things in a $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P^1}$ bundle. Thanks.

Comment: Certainly fibre products of two $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundles will work. Thats it?

Comment: That's it (just wanted to be sure thanks). 

Comment: I guess $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundles over a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle should work also.